How to interpret type-1-error, when omitting fixed effect from mixed model?
A Simulation study with the following task is given:
Do 1000 simulation runs based on simulated data from the model below to explore the following issue:
Do simulations where the regression coefficient $\beta_1$ corresponding to $x_1$ is zero (no treatment effect).
Look at the standard t-test for $\beta_1 = 0$. What is the proportion of rejected null hypotheses from 1000 simulation runs ($\alpha=0.05$)?
Variables:

$y$: outcome of clinical study (effect of medication)
indiv individuals = 20
repl replicate measurements per individual taken on consecutive days after the treatment = 10
explanatory variables:
- $x_1$ ... the treatment (2 treatments) - half of the individuals receive treatment/placebo
- $x_2$ ... the time of measurement (in days, 1...10 (continuous predictor))
- $x_3$ ... indicator coding the individual

Underlying model: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \gamma_1(x_3) + \gamma_2(x_3)*x_2 + \epsilon$
Furthermore $\beta_0 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 1$, $\beta_2 = 0.5$, $\gamma_1(x_3) \sim N(0,4)$ i.i.d., $\gamma_2(x_3) \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d.
I came up with the following code:
library(lmerTest)

Data generation process
sim.data <- function(indiv,repl,param.beta,param.gamma.1,param.gamma.2,param.eps) {
  
  indiv <- indiv          # number of individuals / people
  repl <- repl            
   # number of replications (= number of measurements) per individual
  
  b.0 <-  param.beta[1]    # betas fixed effects
  b.1 <-  param.beta[2]
  b.2 <-  param.beta[3]
  
  x.1 <- rep(rep(0:1, each=repl), length.out=indiv*repl)  
          # Treatment: no,yes
  x.2 <- rep(1:10, length.out=indiv*repl)                
          # day of treatment per individual
  id <- rep(1:indiv, each=repl)                          
          # indicator coding the individual = x.3
  
  gamma.1 <- rnorm(indiv, mean=param.gamma.1[1], sd=param.gamma.1[2])
  gamma.2 <- rnorm(indiv, mean=param.gamma.2[1], sd=param.gamma.2[2])
  
  g1 <- gamma.1[id]   # intercept random effects
  g2 <- gamma.2[id]   # slope random effects
  
  e <- rnorm(length(x.1), mean=param.eps[1], sd=param.eps[2])
  
  y <- b.0 + b.1*x.1 + b.2*x.2 + g1 + g2*x.2 + e
  
  data.sim <- data.frame(x.1 = x.1,
                         x.2 = x.2,
                         x.3 = id,
                         y = y)
  
  return(data.sim)
  
}

set.seed(11525)
data <- sim.data(20,10,c(1,1,0.5),c(0,4),c(0,1),c(0,1))

true.mod <- lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2||x.3), REML = FALSE, 
                  data = data)    

summary(true.mod)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use 
    Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest'] 
    Formula: y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2 || x.3)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   786.7    806.5   -387.4    774.7      194 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6798 -0.5763 -0.0162  0.5099  2.3082 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 x.3      (Intercept) 19.148   4.3758  
 x.3.1    x.2          0.624   0.7899  
 Residual              1.149   1.0720  
Number of obs: 200, groups:  x.3, 20

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   1.0620     1.4028 20.0049   0.757  0.45784   
x.1           1.0050     1.9837 19.9957   0.507  0.61797   
x.2           0.5180     0.1786 20.0132   2.900  0.00884 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) x.1   
x.1 -0.707       
x.2 -0.015  0.000

Simulation
# set amount of simulation runs
n.sim <- 1000

# fitting data under null-hypothesis: b1 == 0 (recalculating y)
data.null <- data
b.1 <- 1    # for clarity
data.null$y <- data.$y-b.1*data$x.1
data.null <- data.null[,-1]

head(data.null)

Description:df [6 × 3]

   x.2 x.3  y
1   1   1   0.8730795   
2   2   1   1.6938862   
3   3   1   0.7454895   
4   4   1   -0.5067670  
5   5   1   1.0773961   
6   6   1   1.3518126   
6 rows

# fitting model under null-hypothesis for simulation
mod.null <- lmer(y ~ x.2 + (1 + x.2||x.3), data = data.null, 
                  REML = FALSE)

# simulation
beta.1.sign.offset <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))

set.seed(1234)

for (i in 1:n.sim) {
    y.sim <- unlist(simulate(mod.null))
    sim.mod <- lmer(y.sim ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2||x.3),
                data=data.frame(data.null, x.1 = data$x.1, 
                             y.sim=y.sim), REML=FALSE)    
 # model including x.1
beta.1.sign.offset[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,5]    
}

# findings:
mean(beta.1.sign.offset < 0.05)  # type 1 error rate

[1] 0.067

Question:
I am unsure about the simulation itself - is it technically correct (usage of simulate())? And how to evaluate the type 1 error rate as it's close to the significance level but also above it?

First you say that B_1 = 0, then you say B_1 = 1.  I'm confused.
